# Rails: ordering compiled arrays by join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I've got a method that builds an array like so:

```
def editing
  @doc = Doc.find(params[:id])
  articles = Article.find(:all, :joins => :docs, :order => 'publications.position')
  unbuilt_edits = articles - @doc.edits.map(&:article)
  unbuilt_edits.each do |article|
    @doc.edits.build(:body => article.body, :article_id => article.id, :doc_id => @doc.id)
  end
end
```

My question is: how to I order `unbuilt_edits` like I did `articles`? As in by `publications.position`? `Publications` is a join table so you know.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Essentially the order breaks if `@doc.edits.map(&:article)` returns not empty. When it's empty it works fine.

Comment: Isn't unbuilt_edits already ordered correctly?

Comment: It seems to be ordered correctly if I'm building it from scratch, but if there's already something in `@doc.edits.map(&:article)` it doesn't behave.

Comment: I think there is more going on here that you're not showing us then.  Looks like the array is correctly ordered, but the edits aren't displaying in order?  Maybe you want to add a position column on the edit model so you can sort by that?

Comment: I considered that, yeah, but it's unnecessary duplication of information. I've got the order correct everywhere else, it's just this one method that's giving me grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would only load the articles that you're interested in:

```
unbuilt_edits = Article.find(:all, :joins => :docs, :order => 'publications.position', :conditions => ['id NOT IN (?)', @doc.edits.map(&:article_id)])
```

This avoids loading articles you're not interested and then removing them from the array.  They should also stay in order if you do it this way.

This assumes article_id is the correct key on the edits model.

You could also just select 'id,body' if that's all you're interested in from the article `:select => 'id,body'`

Comment: That's a better loading line, cheers. But yeah, the order has `edits` on top regardless of their `publications.position`.

Comment: Actually, that breaks something for me after further testing.

Comment: If order is important, you need to add a column to keep track of order, or have them all built out when the Doc is created.  There are other ways to do this, but in the long run, it'll be the most reliable to store the order as a column and then sort on that column.  You may need to add a callback to update the order when publications.position changes.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to cheat and not have to have another column. Thanks for you help.